# problem with dropped pandas column in numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Dropping one column from a dataset and trying to predict it via a linear regression model shouldn't be a problem. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('student-mat.csv',sep=';')

data = data[['G1','G2','G3','studytime','failures','absences']]
predict = 'G3'

X = np.array(data.drop(predict), 1) # error happens here
```

But when I run it, this is the error I get:

```
KeyError: "['G3'] not found in axis"
```

I think it has something to do with the version of numpy that I am using as opposed to the one in the tutorial.

Comment: Where *exactly* does the error pop up? Please include the full error trace.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/oqhpdm... Link to the full error
and in the first lines this is the full error message.... this error repeats for about 13 times

C:\...\...\...\...\...\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])

Comment: Please see why [pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). In any case, it is apparent that the error happens in line `X = np.array(data.drop(predict), 1)`, so all the code that comes *after* is redundant (it is never executed), and it just creates unnecessary clutter (removed). It also says that this is actually a pandas and numpy question, having nothing to do with `scikit-learn` or `regression` (tags removed & replaced with `pandas`).

Comment: You are welcome; remember, by keeping your code [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (among other things) you help possible respondents to help you with your issue.

Comment: You just misplaced the closing brackets. Try: `X = np.array(data.drop(predict, axis=1))` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
X = np.array(data.drop(predict, axis=1))
```